# WearableListenerService - onPeerConnected never called

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I created simple Phone<->Wear App.

Wear app has one Activity with code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {

private TextView mTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
            mTextView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }
    });

    getGoogleApiClient(this).connect();
}


private GoogleApiClient getGoogleApiClient(Context context) {
    return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "onConnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "onConnectionSuspended", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}}
```

And Phone app has one WearableListenerService

```
public class ListenerOfConnection extends WearableListenerService  {

private static final String TAG = "DataLayerListenerServic";


protected GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Toast.makeText(ListenerOfConnection.this, "onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .build();

    googleApiClient.connect();
}


@Override
public void onPeerConnected(Node peer) {
    super.onPeerConnected(peer);
    Toast.makeText(ListenerOfConnection.this, "onPeerConnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    LOGD(TAG, "onPeerConnected: " + peer);
}

@Override
public void onPeerDisconnected(Node peer) {
    super.onPeerDisconnected(peer);
    Toast.makeText(ListenerOfConnection.this, "onPeerDisconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    LOGD(TAG, "onPeerDisconnected: " + peer);
}

public static void LOGD(final String tag, String message) {
    if (Log.isLoggable(tag, Log.DEBUG)) {
        Log.d(tag, message);
    }
}}
```

The problem is that `onPeerConnected` and `onPeerDisconnected` are **never called**, also `onCreate` is not called if I not send any message.

And if i send few messages `onCreate` is called but `onPeerConnected` and `onPeerDisconnected` **never**...

Before questions to me:
1. applicationId is the same
2. `onConnected` is called on wearable Activity

Comment: Your TAG is missing one letter, be careful if you filter logs by its full name

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, the `onPeerConnected` and `onPeerDisconnected` events are only called when your app is running and the *bluetooth* connection between the watch and phone is made or broken. In other words, you will very rarely see these events, and virtually never when you're debugging the two devices sitting on your desk.

If you're trying to do some work when your app first starts up and the API-level connection between the devices is initialized, you'll need to use the `Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes` method instead.

The documentation for this stuff is less than clear...